# How to add blog post and show post in Django web blog

Tags: django

I am learning Django framework using djangogirls tutorial, reading this tutorial, I try to  make a blog. Now I want to add some blog post from forms .py file and show it in this blog but unable to do that, How can I do that in my blog ? please help with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather a generic approach.I hope this helps.

A widget is Django’s representation of an HTML input element. The widget handles the rendering of the HTML, and the extraction of data from a GET/POST dictionary that corresponds to the widget.

You can specify a widget as :

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Many widgets have optional extra arguments; they can be set when defining the widget on the field. In the following example, the years attribute is set for a SelectDateWidget:

```
from django import forms

BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES = ('1980', '1981', '1982')
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = (
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
)

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    birth_year = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=BIRTH_YEAR_CHOICES))
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES)
```

Comment: this is a generic approach but to add a widget to your own blog you need to specify the model of your blog first.